# Find new basis for a set

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following set :
$S=\{(2,4,6,8,10), (10,8,6,4,2), (8,6,4,2,0), (32,32,32,26,32), (10,10,10,10,10)\}$

Using the Gauss-Jordan algorithm I have determined that the lines corresponding to vector 1, 2 and 3 are linearly independents while the other lines are null.

Thus said the vectors $(2,4,6,8,10)$, $(10,8,6,4,2)$ and $(32,32,32,26,32)$ form the basis of my set.
I'm trying to find a new set that would span the basis of $S$ but have no idea where to start looking.

I did find some examples using columns matrices but we are required to always use row matrices.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's a row matrix?

Answer (score 1):

For instance, now that you know the dimension is three, look at the last three vectors.  They are independent, which can be seen by row-reduction, hence form a basis.

You could try sets of three of the vectors in $S$ as the rows of a matrix, row-reduce and see if they're independent.